# Split word jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some word have to split, but how can i split two things using one time only ? Example, `"avg/hulk.swf" and "dance.swf"` both I only need their name `hulk` and `dance` , How to write split jquery in one time to split `avg/` and `.swf` that I want ? Because all get from DB , so some contain `avg/` and `.swf` some only `.swf` .

```js
var test = "avg/hulk.swf";
var keyword = test.split("avg/")[1];

alert(keyword);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show"></div>
```

Comment: you go to regular expression

Comment: so your problem is that keyword sometimes contains ".swf"? Why not use an other split to get rid of that the same way you got rid of "avg/"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

you can use `split()` then `pop()` and`slice()` after

```
    function getName(path){
      return (path.split('/').pop()).slice(0,-4); 
    }

    alert( getName("dance.swf") + "\n" + getName("avg/hulk.swf"));
```

**[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2519955e/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove them from string.

```
var test = "avg/hulk.swf";
var keyword = test.replace(/avg\/|\.swf/g,'');

alert(keyword);
```

Answer (score 1):

its only works for your given context.

```
var test = "avg/hulk.swf";
var keyword = test.split("avg/")[1].split(".")[0];

alert(keyword);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1cg5oy0g/)

Comment: This will fail at `test = "hulk.swf"`. Should split using `"/"`, than split `pop()` using dot.

Answer (score 0):

```
1    var str = "JQUERY By Example";

2    var n = str.charAt(2)



//Output will be "U"
```

so yeah here is an example for 1 letter, and here is if you want to get a specific word:

```
var str="Hello world!";
var n=str.substr(2,3)
//Output will be "llo"
```

Hope this helps!